# Missing value imputation based on regression for one half of the data (using R)

Tags: r, imputation

I have data that consist of two waves of interviewees responses to a set of survey questions. It's not a panel study, but they had a set of question for the first waves that partly corresponds to the questionnaire of the second wave. To give you an hypothetical example, consider this as the structure of my survey data:

```
id   wave   question1   question2   question3
1    1      #           NA          #
2    1      #           NA          #
3    1      #           NA          #
1    2      #           #           NA
2    2      #           #           NA
3    2      #           #           NA
```

So I have an id variable that will start from 1 again for the second wave but this does not mean that `id==1[wave==1] = id==1[wave==2]`. So it's not a panel. In addition, I have "question1" for both waves, "question2" only for the second wave and "question3" only for the first wave.

Now, can I impute missing wave-two-data for my variable "question3" based on a regression of "question3" on a set of other variables that exists for both waves? In other words, can I impute missing "question3"-data based on `lm(question3 ~ question1_a + question1_b + question1_c)` where all of these question1_k are available for both waves?

- Would this be a legitimate method (assuming that my linear model predicts "question3" well enough)?
- How would I implement this?

Comment: I think the first question is more of a statistics question, use `http://stats.stackexchange.com`.

Comment: It's both, no? The first question sure is a stats question that would be better placed in *Cross Validated*, the second questions is more technical in nature...

Comment: Regression would be a possible method to impute your data (assuming that wave 1 and wave 2 are compareable regarding the targed variable), but there are more powerful methods. Here you can finde info and code for some nice packages in r: https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/tutorial-powerful-packages-imputing-missing-values/. Depending on what you plan to do with the data you might also have to make a decision about single or multiple imputation.

Comment: This is really helpful, thanks @TinglTanglBob! Though I'm wondering if you can also simply concentrate on *one* variable's missing values and impute values there, given that all these examples display methods for imputation based on missing data in the *overall* data set.

Comment: With regard to multiple and single imputation I'm really thinking *multiple* is what I wanna go with, but do you know about any rules of thumb here? My aim is to run a regression model and there's just one (more or less central) variable that has roughly 50% missings. Now mean imputation would probably be against the odds of that one variable but at least leaves me with a sound overall model. But since I'm not only interested in the overall mode but also in the influence of this one variable I'm leaning towards multiple imputation...

Comment: Yes, i think i would go with multiple imputation too. Single imputation always has the flawor of circular analysis to me. First you impute data using information from available data and afterwards you use all the variables to show some relation between them. In worst case your post-imputation analyses shows just the association that was created by the imputation (or at least this relation might be overestimated). For the post-imputation analysis i would also do it once with and once without imputed values and compare the results to see if something totaly strange is going on.

Comment: But since im not an expert on data imputation i think it would be a good idea to repost your question on cross validated, as suggested by @AndreElrico allready. I think chances are good that someone with data imputation expertise will read your question over there and deliver some helpful input.

Comment: mice is usually the go to package for multiple imputation of survey data. Be very careful your missing data mechanism is MNAR. (missing not at random). This is a good intro to the package: https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v045i03/v45i03.pdf . Especially sections 3.1 and 6.2 might be interesting.